# What is the difference between elements.enabled and elements_i18n.enabled?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, status

It appears, toggling the status button on an entry affects only the `elements.enabled` value.  What affects the `elements_i18n.enabled` value?  When and how would we choose to update the `enabled` column in the `elements_i18n` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your section is enabled in multiple locales, each locale will get its own status lightswitch setting, which maps back to `elements_i18n.enabled`. It’s how you can have individual entries enabled/disabled on a per-locale basis.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess `elements_i18n.enabled` is written as `localeEnabled` throughout the code.